# syntax error in photon networking for unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, syntax-error

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

I'm not sure of what this error is.

There are no other syntax errors in the code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NetworkManager : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings("1.0");
    }
    private const string roomName = "RoomName";
    private RoomInfo[] roomsList;

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (!PhotonNetwork.connected)
        {
            GUILayout.Label(PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed.ToString());
        }
        else if (PhotonNetwork.room == null)
        {
            // Create Room
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100, 100, 250, 100), "Start Server"))
                PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomName + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"), true, true, 5);

            // Join Room
            if (roomsList != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < roomsList.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100, 250 + (110 * i), 250, 100), "Join " + roomsList[i].name))
                        PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(roomsList[i].name);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnReceivedRoomListUpdate()
    {
        roomsList = PhotonNetwork.GetRoomList();
    }
    void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        Debug.Log("Connected to Room");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: length is where the error is

Comment: It should be `roomsList.GetLength(0)` . See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It should be `roomsList.GetLength(0)` . See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
            int i = 0;
            foreach (RoomInfo game in PhotonNetwork.GetRoomList())
            {
                if (GUI.Button(new Rect(5, (40 * (i + 2)) + 10, Screen.width - 10, 40), "Join" + game.name, _skin.button))
                {
                    PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(game.name);
                }
                i++;
            }
```